# Counting number of words in a text file

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to count the number of words from a text file, namely this, to start.

> This is a test of the word count program. This is only a test. If your
>   program works successfully, you should calculate that there are 30
>   words in this file.

I am using StreamReader to put everything from the file into a string, and then use the .Split method to get the number of individual words, but I keep getting the wrong value when I compile and run the program.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class WordCounter
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string inFileName = null;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the file to process:");
        inFileName = Console.ReadLine();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inFileName);

        int counter = 0;
        string delim = " ,.";
        string[] fields = null;
        string line = null;

        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }



        fields = line.Split(delim.ToCharArray());
        for(int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        sr.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("The word count is {0}", counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use regular expression, e.g.:

```cs
int count = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b\w+\b").Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work for you:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class WordCounter
{
static void Main()
{
      string inFileName = null;

      Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the file to process:");
      inFileName = Console.ReadLine();

      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inFileName);

      int counter = 0;
      string delim = " ,."; //maybe some more delimiters like ?! and so on
      string[] fields = null;
      string line = null;

      while(!sr.EndOfStream)
      {
         line = sr.ReadLine();//each time you read a line you should split it into the words
         line.Trim();
         fields = line.Split(delim.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
         counter+=fields.Length; //and just add how many of them there is
      }


      sr.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("The word count is {0}", counter);
}
```

}

Comment: Why not `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: @NikoDrašković What if the file has 1000 or 10000 or 10M words? Since I've started with C long ago, I would never use a ReadToEnd, it's a habit but think that reading into memory something that is in a file in cases when I can read it in chunks isn't the best option. Also this illustrates OP's errors in code.

Comment: Your code worked, but I don't understand why. When I only output fields.Length, it gives me a value of 3. How come, counter+=fields.Length gives 30, when counter was initialized as 0?

Comment: What if the file is 10M and has a single line? :) Jokes aside, if the file really was big, I'd consider using [Michael Abrashes](http://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/ch16/16-01.html) approach. If it wasn't I'd use `ReadToEnd()`, though your point in reading files in chunks is valid!

Comment: @NikoDrašković Good point for a single line :-). Never thought of that really. I must try it. And I was thinking on a good old fscanf() or fgets() kind of things. Not that advanced file reading.

Comment: @user1781027 += operator does essentially counter = counter + fields.Length. Hence each time you read a line of text, you split it into words and add the number of words within array (fields.Length) to the previous words count. This is how these things should be done when you are learning to program.

Comment: What does the .Trim and StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires do?

Comment: The Trim() is a method of a string that clears all blank (' ') characters from the beginning and the end of the string (in your case the line) and string StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires will exclude those strings that are made of blank characters (for instance if you had two blank characters between two words).

Comment: If .Trim removed all the spaces in between the words, wouldn't line.Split() only split the words that are separated by commas, periods and so on?

Comment: The Trim() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx works like this, if you have a string "  Some string with leading and trailing white spaces   " and apply Trim on it you get "Some string with leading and trailing white spaces". Just "all leading and trailing white-space characters" are deleted, not the ones between the words.

Answer (score 1):

A couple hints.

1. What if you just have the sentence "hi" what would be your output?
2. Your counter calculation is: from 0 through `fields.Length`, increment counter. How are `fields.Length` and your counter related?

Comment: 1. When I just put "hi" in the text file, it tells me that the word count is 1.

Answer (score 0):

you're probably getting a one off error, try something like this

```
    counter = 0;
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        fields = line.Split(delim.ToCharArray());
        counter += field.length();
    }
```

there is no need to iterate over the array to count the elements when you can get the number directly

Comment: I the text file given to me, the paragraph was arranged into 3 lines, with the last line containing only "in this file." When I tried Console.WriteLine(line); in my program without anything else, it just outputted "in this file." Do you know why it just read the last line?

Comment: ah,k srry I didn't look at it carefully enough, it's because read line  reads only one line at a time so you are reading all thre but only counting the last one read

Comment: I changed my code so that it is now 

    line += sr.ReadLine + " ";

and it now outputs the entire string when I display the string on Console.WriteLine. However, it gives me a value of 35 when I try to display fields.Length. Any idea why?

Comment: Technically 29 words, but we're supposed to count the number 30 as a word too, so 30 words in total.

Comment: I couldn't say with out seeing the input.  my guess is that you'r delimiter is wrong and you're splitting some words in two. try using just " " as a delimiter and see what happens.  look at the file and think of how delim is splitting it.  you'll figure it out.  I think you're pretty close already

Comment: actually I just looked at nicks code and he has the same approach, but removes extra space and null fields.  that's why his works and mine doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Easy method using Linq to Count number of words in a text file
/// www.techhowdy.com
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FP_WK13
{
    static class Util
    {
       
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(string yourtextfile)
        {
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(yourtextfile);
            string result = string.Empty;
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return line;
            }
            reader.Close();
        }



        // Word Count 

        public static int GetWordCount(string str)
        {         
            int words = 0;
            string s = string.Empty;
            var lines = GetLines(str);

            foreach (var item in lines)
            {
                s = item.ToString();
                words = words +  s.Split(' ').Length;
                
            }

            return words;
            
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put only code, Please add some description how you got this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System;
namespace solution
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var readFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test\my.txt");
            var str = readFile.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Number of words: " + str.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is for the .txt file